# Design Dialogs for different locales in a multi-locale site

Tags: aem

How to change design dialog content in specific locale?Example the design specific constructs that would be different accross locales were logo, branding elements etc... Please suggest various alternatives and best approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design dialog are not locale or site specific in case of multisites rolled out on same instance of AEM. Design dialog properties gets stored on template/component basis in designs (`/etc/designs/<your-site>/jcr:content/<path/page component name>/<component>`). You can look at the sample for geometrixx site @ `/etc/designs/geometrixx/jcr:content/page/logo`

For the scenarios where in the content/imagery that needs to change per site/locales you should use normal dialogs.

For components like header and footer which needs to stay consistent across site and usually the requirement is that they should be authored once and not be edited every time a new page is created, you could use iparsys component for the inheritance of these sections to pages in the hierarchy. This would require the inheritance system to be setup on a base page/template from which other templates extend so that inheritance get extended to all templates.

Comment: Is there no way we could have locale specific design pages and associate those design pages to respective locale sites while the rest of content came from the 'MSM-ing' of parent site?

Comment: No, there is no concept of locale specific design pages, unless your locales have different templates which is neither advised not efficient way of managing templates in AEM.

Comment: Just a thought : Isn't this one more appropriate that templates define the differences of layout, while the design pages define the differences of styling on those "same" templates. Thereby designs can be varied to provide variations to style related imagery / content for the same set of layouts (templates) by differentiating amongst designs ?

Comment: Yes it is, and this feature is available via template editor in AEM 6.2 not sure about how designs are handled when using template editor but for versions below it there isnt a choice.

Another option could be to use separate designs for locale sites, havent done that thou but its quite possible.